# What does this decode to?

Tags: encoding

I found this, and want to know what it decodes to and what type of encoding it is:

```
ZGMzMGRjODlAc25hcGpveS5jb20=
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is, as I expected, Base64. You can recognize it by the equal sign at the end. It translates to some sort of email address:

[image]

If you want to know more about Base64, there is a great [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: Quick clarification: Base64 doesn't always have an equal sign in it, but `=` or `+` are signals that it's probably base64.

Comment: Didn't know the + sign was used as well. The chance of it containing an equal sign is 2/3 by the way, as it's a space filler for incomplete 3-byte sequences.

Comment: VGhhbmtzISAuLi4uYW5kIHNvcnJ5LCBTbmFwSm95IDsp

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer Is this question and your comment a very geeky kind of spam? :)

Comment: Heh, no, I'm not that smart. ;) Really, I just wanted to decode their jobs puzzle but was too tired to figure it out completely on my own.

Comment: FYI - I never applied for the job, nor did I intend to. I was just curious.

Answer (score 3):

The encoding is called Base64, and it decodes to some email address.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When in need of *detailed* and *specific* information about an Internet standard I always look and see if there's an [RFC (Request For Comments)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc.html) for it. For the Base64-encoding, take a look at this document: [The Base16, Base32, and Base64 Data Encodings (RFC 4648)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt).

@Simon Verbeke: There are two versions of the Base64 alphabet. Take a look at the following tables in the RFC 4648.

*"Table 1: The Base 64 Alphabet"* ("base64")

*"Table 2: The "URL and Filename safe" Base 64 Alphabet"* ("base64url")

*NOTE: The "base64url" encoding should not be regarded as the same as the "base64" encoding and should not be referred to as only "base64".*